# SBT + Idea 13 => Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using [SBT](https://github.com/sbt/sbt) + Idea 13.1.1 and I have all my SBT file in red:

```
name := "Transformer"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.2.0",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "test"
)
```

It's saying

> Cannot resolve symbol name/version

But Seq is ok. But it's all good to run the app from SBT cmd or even from Idea directly running the main or scalatests. I know it's not a lot information to troubleshoot but I don't know what to check else. Tell me if you have an idea I'll provide everything.

Cheers

Comment: Would there be a simple sample SBT project we could try reproducing this issue with?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To fix this, remove the folder `.idea` and reimport the project.

The root cause remains a mystery...

Comment: I have a very similar problem in Idea 14 but this solution did not work for me.

Comment: @Jono did you ever find a solution? I've having this same problem now.

Comment: Still applicable in 2017.

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue in Intellij UE 2017.3.5

Comment: This issue is still exists in 2018.3 version. So annoying why the paid product can not attend to this very old issue?

Comment: I made sure I had the scala and sbt IntelliJ plugins, invalidated caches and restarted IntelliJ, but this is what finally fixed the issues.

Comment: it looks like you are creating a project based on .IDEA. you need to create a project based on sbt

Comment: No, it is based on SBT, that is why we can safely delete the .ides folder (ignored in git) and reimport

Comment: Still occurs Version: 2019.2.4 Ultimate.

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar problem when I updated to `SBT 0.13.7`. `IntelliJ` started marking operators such as `:=` and `++` in red with message "Cannot resolve symbol"

My steps to fix this solution were as follows:

1. In `IntelliJ` under `Files | Settings`, I switched my `SBT Runner` to use a Custom Launcher (and gave my path to `sbt-launch.jar` which for me was `/opt/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar`).
2. After testing that I can still compile after #1 above, I then had to invalidate the cache and restart; under `Files | Invalidate Caches` / Restart...

That's it! :-)

Comment: Thanks so much.. Invalidating the Cache and restarting solved my problem.. after being really struck when my project suddenly stopped working !!!

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue in Intellij UE 2017.3.5

Answer (score 3):

In case none of the other solutions work and you are in the same boat as me, where you see a `Cannot resolve symbol ...` in the `build.sbt` and all files that have sbt dependencies, and where there are no sbt dependencies in `External Libraries`, running `File | New | Module from Existing Sources...` and selecting the `build.sbt` may fix it for you as it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on 14.1.2; in my case adding

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" % "test"
```

and then trying to

```
import org.scalatest._
```

Would resulted in: cannot resolve symbol scalatest

Downgrading sbt (0.13.8 -> 0.13.7); in build.properties solved the problem.

here are more [details](http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/scalatest-intellij-problem/).

Comment: The problem you had is for a specific missing dependency and it was probably reflected in other places (e.g sbt -> compile will also fail). It looks like the problem they referring is more general in intellij

Answer (score 1):

Updating my `build.properties` from `0.13.8` to a newer version, like `0.13.15`, solved it for me. [Reference github issue.](https://github.com/coursier/coursier/issues/245)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in IDEA 14.0. Nothing above worked.

Upgrade to IDEA 14.1.1 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting IntelliJ fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was about the `.idea` folder, if it is not included the `codeStyles`, `Modules`, `libraries` , it is giving that error. I fix it with import that folder from another project that has it.Then restart `IntelliJ`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be changes in the recent JDK (I was  using Ver 16)  the  sbt project build engine  doesn't expect. In IntelliJ this causes the build.sbt  to be misread - so that  sbt does not recognise Seq.

Scala 2 code is based around JDK 8-11, what you would expect from its age -  later changes to the JDK16 string class looks broken to  sbt (version 1.28)
IntelliJ reports:

error while loading String, class file  '/modules/java.base/java/lang String.class' is broken

Setting the JDK to 8-11 resolves the problem.