# Idea SBT support: cannot resolve symbol in vanilla project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using Intellij UE 2017.3. The steps that I undertook were:

1. Create a new project from Lightbend templates
2. Check import sbt sources (tried without as well)
3. Try the suggested solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845862/sbt-idea-13-cannot-resolve-symbol)

As a result in my build.sbt nothing seems to be imported, regardless of whether before or after trying the suggested fixes, (even the Dependencies object in /project folder).

Here is Dependencies object contents:

```
import sbt._

object Dependencies {
  lazy val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
}
```

I attach below screenshot with the errors and project structure. Note that in External Libraries scalatest version is different from scalaVersion, but former is correctly imported in Dependencies object.

[image]

The errors that appear are:

- for Dependencies: Cannot resolve symbol
- for settings: Cannot resolve reference settings with such signature, Cannot resolve symbol settings
- for List: Type mismatch: expected: Def.SettingsDefinition,
  actual Seq[Def.Setting[_]]
- for name and libraryDependencies: too many
  arguments for method settings

sbt.version is 1.1.1

Comment: What is `algorithms1_5_17.iml` in your root? Isn't in fact the single-file project configuration used? Maybe the `.idea` folder is ignored completely?

Comment: Try re-generating project configuration files by [re-importing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-support.html#import_sbt) project from build.sbt file from scratch in IDE.

Comment: Excellent @Andrey - do you want to copy your comment to answer so I can accept it?