# Where to put "enablePlugins" in SBT?

Tags: sbt

Following [this tutorial](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/windows.html), I am asked to add `enablePlugins(WindowsPlugin)` to my SBT configuration.

I did this by stating exactly this line in my build.sbt but all I get is "Cannot resolve symbol". Do I need to add the dependency somewhere?

Is this an *auto plugin* and can anyone explain to me what an *auto plugin* actually is and how I use it?

**UPDATE**: My `build.sbt` looks like that:

```
name := "ApplicationName"

version := "0.3-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

enablePlugins(WindowsPlugin)

mainClass in assembly := Some("application.ConfigEditorApplication")
assemblyJarName in assembly := s"application-$version.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.9"
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" % "scala-logging_2.13" % "3.9.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.6.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock" % "4.4.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-scala_2.13" % "1.11.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-scala-scalatest_2.13" % "1.11.3"
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.sbt` ? It is difficult to help without seeing the code.

Comment: I do not have a working `build.sbt`. But the question is more: How do I enable an automatic plugin? Where do I put the `enablePlugin` clause?

Comment: You did not mention WHICH symbol is not resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem: From the beginning, I suspected, that the plugin needs to be added before it can be enabled. Unfortunately, nothing of that sort was mentioned in the tutorial I was following.

The plugin which has to be added is the *native-packager* plugin: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.0")`.

Comment: That's the first thing https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/gettingstarted.html tells you to do

Comment: Indeed it does. But there is no way to know where to put this line (because it does not work in the build.sbt) and what the latest version is. For someone who just switched to sbt it is really difficult to gather.

Comment: Changing "Add it to your plugins.sbt" to "Add it to your project/plugins.sbt" would be a welcome change assuming less sbt knowledge, I think. Adding a link to the relevant section of the sbt documentation (about plugins in general) would also be welcome.

Comment: I will create a pull request :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should create your auto pluggin in your `build.sbt`. The `build.sbt` file must be at the root of your projet, at the same level with the file `src`.

You have information about it [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/gettingstarted.html) and [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Plugins.html).

In the page you mentioned they say you should set this in your build.sbt. Try this.

```
// general package information (can be scoped to Windows)
maintainer := "Josh Suereth <joshua.suereth@typesafe.com>"
packageSummary := "test-windows"
packageDescription := """Test Windows MSI."""

// wix build information
wixProductId := "ce07be71-510d-414a-92d4-dff47631848a"
wixProductUpgradeId := "4552fb0e-e257-4dbd-9ecb-dba9dbacf424"
```

**UPDATE**

Also, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845862/sbt-idea-13-cannot-resolve-symbol) which is related to yours. It is true, it is an old one, but it might give you some hints. Some answers suggest performing updatings, others deleting and then reimporting the project.

Comment: I added now my `build.sbt` to my question. For `enablePlugins(WindowsPlugin)` IntelliJ says: _Cannot resolve symbol WindowsPlugin_

Comment: Did you install WIX Toolset? It is required in the tutorial. Also, did you check your sbt version? There are two behaviours for different sbt versions, as you can see in the tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I did install the WIX Toolset and I use sbt version 1.2.8 which should support `enablePlugins(WindowsPlugin)` according to the tutorial.

Comment: Did you add the wix build info? That is mandatory according to the tutorial.

Comment: I did but I don't think that these properties have anything to do with `Cannot resolve symbol` problem.

Comment: Thank you! If that was the solution it should be able to run sbt on the command line, right? Let's try that.

Comment: There were several answers, some of them concerning running from `IntelijIdea` also.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem: I had to add the plugin before I could enable it. Please see my answer to this question. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Glad for you! I hope I could give some help.